# Cannot convert double [] [] to double **

Tags: c++, double

I ve got a function that takes 3 parameteres, first one is **double.

```
 normalizeDataZeroMeanUnitSD(double ** trainingActions, int numberOfTrainingActions, int descriptorDimension)
```

When I call it from main, I am trying to use normalizeDataZeroMeanUnitSD(data, 681, 24); however, I am receiving

```
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'double [681][24]' to 'double **'
```

This is how I construct the data array:

```
fstream infile;
infile.open("gabor\\Data.txt");

double data[681][24];

while (!infile.eof()) 
     {
        for(int j=0;j<681;j++) 
        {
            for(int k=0; k<24;k++) 
            {

                infile >> data[j][k];

           }

        }

 } 
 infile.close();
```

Is there a way to do the same using **data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use any of the following declarations. Both are equivalent.

```
NormalizeDataZeroMeanUnitSD(double trainingActions[][24], int numberOfTrainingActions, int descriptorDimension)

NormalizeDataZeroMeanUnitSD(double trainingActions[681][24], int numberOfTrainingActions, int descriptorDimension)
```

When you declare a 2D array it takes up contiguous memory locations. So you need to specify at least the number of columns (in case of row major architecture).

For row major and column major definitions, have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

For your edited question, yes you can declare using `**data`. Dynamically allocate the `data` array. But remember to free it when you're done with it.

```
double **data=new double*[681];
for (int i=0;i<681;i++)
{
  data[i]=new double[24];
}

//do what you want to do


for (int i=0;i<681;i++)
{
  delete [] data[i];
}

delete [] data;
```

Now your function prototype can be like `void func(double **pp)` because `data` is a pointer not a 2D array.

Comment: The second one is so misleading, pass by reference instead of pointer.

Answer (score 6):

The error is pretty clear: Datatype `double [681][24]` is not the same as `double **`. While it's true that `double[681]` can decay to a pointer to its first element (thus, `double*`), that does not imply that `double[681][24]` can decay to `double**`.

Think about it this way: `double**` implies a pointer to many pointers. But `double[][]` does not have ANY pointers in it. At best, an array of ANY dimensions still only has, at very most, one pointer: to the beginning of its contiguous storage.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a template:

```
template<std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
void normalizeDataZeroMeanUnitSD(double (&trainingActions)[M][N], int descriptorDimension)
{
   for( std::size_t m = 0; m < M; ++m )
   {
      for( std::size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n )
      {
          trainingActions[m][n] = ...;
      }
   }
}
```

But beware of code bloat if you call this with many differently sized arrays.

Comment: +1; this is probably the best solution. And I wouldn't worry about bloat: If you need it, you need it. IMO, This is much cleaner than passing a `double*` and two dimension size args.

Comment: "Code bloat" isn't quite the applicable term here since the compiler adds the needed code for you. You are right that this could result in an oversized executable. However, the real problem with this is that you need to know the size at compile time, which may not be feasible.

Comment: Pass array by reference, so `M` can be deduced.

Comment: This is fine if you don't mind restricting the dimensions to compile-time constants. You can drop the other function parameters, since they're now redundant.

Comment: @tenfour: No, it's not being passed by reference. It's decaying to a pointer, so that `M` can't be deduced. `double (&trainingActions)[M][N]` would be a reference. (At least, it was before I corrected the answer).

Answer (score 3):

A 2d array is a continuous area of storage. The function expects a pointer to pointers. These are incompatible.

Comment: Ok but how can I overcome this having the 2d double array?

Comment: @snakeplissken: you'll have to create an array of 681 `double*`, and initialize each one to be a pointer to one row of your 2-D array.

Answer (score 3):

The function expects an array of pointers to arrays; you have an array of arrays. Some options are:

- change the function to take a more friendly type, perhaps `double*` pointing to the first element of a contiguous 2-dimensional array; or
- build a separate array of pointers pointing to each row of your 2-dimensional array; or
- restructure your data into an array of pointers to arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a constructive answer for how to make it work.

Basically, you need to generate an array that has pointers to each 1D slice of your 2D array.

```
double data[N][M] = {...};
double *dataPtrs[N];

for(size_t n=0; n<N; ++n) {
  dataPtrs[n] = data[n];
}

normalizeDataZeroMeanUnitSD(dataPtrs, N, M); // order of N and M might be wrong
```

Answer (score 3):

Yay, I get to rant about this again.

In C++, despite having similar syntax, 2D arrays are NOT jagged arrays. 2D arrays (`double foo[681][24]`) are allocated contiguously in memory. When you deference a 2D array (`foo[j][i]`) it actually does *(foo+24*i+j). This is all done under the hood. The `sizeof(foo)==sizeof(double)*681*24`.

Jagged arrays are (`double** bar;`). This is a bunch of different arrays: first, you allocate an array of pointer, 268 members long. Each pointer will point to an array of doubles, 24 elements long. Bar is just a pointer, so `sizeof(bar)==sizeof(void*)`.

More annoyingly, 2D arrays (or a static array of any dimension) behave the opposite of all other types in C++ in the following reguard: they are passed implicitly by reference, causing the weird phenomenon below.

```
void foo(double bar[24][24]) { std::cout << sizeof(bar) << std::endl;}
int main() {
  double test[24][24];
  std::cout << sizeof(test) << std::endl;//returns sizeof(double)*24*24
  foo(test);//returns sizeof(void*), implicitly passed by reference, opossite of the rest of c++!
```

Comment: Arrays of any dimension are passed as a pointer to the first element (which in the case of a 2-D array will itself have pointer-to-array type). This is indeed annoying, although it's not specific to 2-D arrays.

Comment: Pass test by reference instead of pointer to get the expected result.

Comment: `void foo(double bar[24][24])` is equivalent to `void foo(double *bar[24])`. Use `void foo(double (&bar)[24][24])` to get expected result.

Comment: @Jarod42 while this is a true statement, the fact that if you do `typedef int foo4[4];` that sizeof(objects of type foo4) is not consistent is...annoying.

Answer (score 2):

`double[][]` is not the same thing as `double**`.

`double**` is a pointer to pointers.
`double[][]` is a 2-dimensional array allocated as continuous storage.

In order to pass a "2-dimensional array" to the function, you need to create an array of pointers to arrays. For example:

```
double* array_2d[681];
for(unsigned int i=0; i<681; ++i) {
    array_2d[i] = new double[24];
}
normalizeDataZeroMeanUnitSD(array_2d, 681, 24);
```

Remember to later delete[] each element of `array_2d`!

Better yet, change `normalizeDataZeroMeanUnitSD` to take a reference to `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, and you no longer have to worry about memory management, nor passing the correct dimensions to the function.