# How to convert a two-dimensional array to a pointer of pointers

Tags: c++

Suppose you have a two-dimensional array which has been initialized like

```
int M[5][5] = { {1,3,4,2,5},
                {3,5,1,6,2},
                {7,5,6,2,0},
                {6,2,9,7,6},
                {1,0,8,5,2} };
```

This `M` will be passed as a parameter to a function. However the function only accepts `int**` as parameter, not `int [][5]`.

My question is, how to do this conversion?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan please read the question again. Your comment does not relate to it.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That won't work; `p` could not be passed as an `int**`, it would be an `int***`.

Comment: @mbratch: why should it accept it? a bidimensional matrix is not an array of pointers, and by no it is directly convertible to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot convert double \[\] \[\] to double \*\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731524/cannot-convert-double-to-double) `int **` and `int [][]` are very different things. See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21731756/1072468).

Comment: M declared like this is an array, not a pointer. if M were allocated with mallocs, then it would work. with gcc : error: cannot convert 'int (*)[5]' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'void f(int**)'

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev  hmm.. deleted...

Comment: @MatteoItalia agreed.

Answer (score 3):

An array of pointers to pointers and a bidimensional array are completely different data structures in C:

- `int **` normally refers to an *array of pointers*, each of which points to a different row (allocated elsewhere)
- `int [5][5]` under the hood is a plain linear array where the rows are stored one after each other, and the compiler automatically performs the calculations on the index to access the right element.

So, having an `int[5][5]`, you have to build the array of pointers by yourself, which will act as an "index" for the rows of your matrix.

```
int * m2[5];
for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    m2[i]=M[i];
f(m2);
```

Comment: Or even `int* m2[5] = {M[0], M[1], M[2], M[3], M[4]}; f(m2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
template<unsigned...>struct indexes {};
template<unsigned Max, unsigned...Is>struct make_indexes:make_indexes<Max-1,Max-1,Is...>{};
template<unsigned...Is>struct make_indexes<0,Is...>:indexes<Is...>{};

template< class T, std::size_t X, std::size_t Y, unsigned...Is >
std::array<T*, X> as_jagged_helper( T(&arr)[X][Y], indexes<Is...> ) {
  return {arr[Is]...};
}

template< class T, std::size_t X, std::size_t Y, unsigned...Is >
std::array<T*, X> as_jagged( T(&arr)[X][Y] ) {
  return as_jagged_helper(arr, make_indexes<X>());
}
```

then simply call `f(&(as_jagged(M)[0]));`